# Mimecast API authentication issue

Tags: api, authentication

trying to connect to endpoint with all needed headers defined: 
https://us-api.mimecast.com/api/login/login.

Error message receieved : 0018 Client update required

Did anyone encounter/solve this issue?

{
    "meta": {
        "status": 401
    },
    "data": [],
    "fail": [
        {
            "key": {
                "username": "datadash@itprosusa.com",
                "tokenType": "key",
                "verifyOnly": false
            },
            "errors": [
                {
                    "code": "err_xdk_client_update_required",
                    "message": "0018 Client update required",
                    "retryable": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same error message when trying to get Access key and Secret Key. You can actually get these in the Mimecast portal UI by going to: **Administration** | **Services** | **API Applications**, then **Add API Application** fill in the details and wait 30 minutes. After 30 minutes click on your newly created API application and select **Create Keys**, fill in the required information and it will provide you with your Access key and Secret key used for API calls.

If this doesn't answer your question or help you I would suggest getting in contact with Mimecast Support, they are usually pretty good!

Comment: When trying to create keys in this way, Mimecast says you must enter the email address "of a service account that already exists." How do you create a service account? I always get the message "The supplied address may not be used for this purpose", regardless of what email I try to use.